# Can we change the hostname of Docker Container running in VM?

Tags: docker, hostname, docker-container, docker-run

I am creating an elasticsearch image and want to run the container on some remote machine.

Suppose the machine hostname is `"abc.com"`, so I am accessing the URL as `"abc.com:9200"` to access elasticsearch. After testing successfully, this container will be deployed to Kubernetes.
But to access elasticsearch (for filebeat, kibana and logstash) I need some static hostname so that while accessing it from different applications will be easy.
I am trying to make the hostname `"elasticsearch"` and want it to access as `"http://elasticsearch:9200"`.

PS: I am new to Docker, and want to clear my doubts by asking silly questions

I have tried adding "--hostname" and "--add-host", both didnt worked.
`docker run -d --name=elasticsearch \ --network=elk \ -p=9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 \ --hostname "elasticsearch" \ elasticsearch:7.17.6`

Expecting to get the response by accessing "http://elsaticsearch:9200"

Comment: Docker itself can't manage the DNS in the surrounding environment.  `docker run --hostname` only sets what the container believes its own hostname is, which is very occasionally useful (I don't remember if Elasticsearch publishes this name in the `/_index/nodes` listing for example) but doesn't affect other containers or other hosts at all.

Comment: (You need to set up your other components so that the host names are configurable; it doesn't really work in practice to hard-code host names and require every environment to have identical networking and deployment setup.)